# Find the position vector of the point R that is closest to the origin on the plane a'x + b'y + c'z = e

Tags: linear-algebra

(a) Write down the Cartesian equation for the plane through the point Q(1,0,0) with normal **n** = -$
\sqrt{6}
$ **i** - $
\sqrt{2}
$ **j** - **k** and compute the distance of the origin from this plane.

(b) Let *ax + by + cz* = *e* be the equation of a plane in space. Divide this equation by a real number to give *a'x + b'y + c'z* = *e'* such that *$ a'^2$* + *$ b'^2$* + *$ c'^2$* = 1 and *e'* $>=$ 0. Show that *e'* is the distance of the plane to the origin.

(c) Find the position vector of the point *R* that is closest to the origin on the plane with equation in the primed form of part (b).

(d) Consider the plane given by the equation in the primed form of part (b). Explain why each plane containing the origin is described by two distinct equations of this form. Explain why each plane that does not contain the origin has a unique equation of this form.

-- I was able to solve parts (a) and (b) and I will describe how I did those below. If anyone is able to help me with parts (c) and (d) I would very much appreciate it. Thank you!

(a) Plane: $\sqrt{6}$x + $\sqrt{2}$y + z = $\sqrt{6}$ and the distance was d = $\sqrt{6}$/3

(b) I divided by a real number k and got that $a^2$+$b^2$+$c^2$=$k^2$.

**n** = $a$**i** + $b$**j** + $c$**k** is a normal vector to the plane ax + by + cz = e.

$|n|^2$ = $a^2$+$b^2$+$c^2$ = $k^2$
, therefore k = |n| , (taking positives since length is positive)

let P($x_0$,$y_0$,$z_0$) be a point on the plane

then **n**$.$**OP** = a$x_0$+b$y_0$+c$z_0$=e (from eqn of plane)

therefore d = |**n**$.$**OP**| = e/k = e'

--Again, if someone could show me how to do parts (c) and (d) it would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!!